# Error run Joomla 3.4.5 on CentOS 6.7 installed Sentora panel 1.0.3

Tags: php, joomla, centos6, sentora

I am using CentOS 6.7 and installed Sentora panel 1.0.3 but when I run Joomla 3.4.5 it alerts "`Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.10 or higher to run this version of Joomla!`" while my php is 5.3.3.

I run `php -v` to check

> PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2015 17:39:00) Copyright (c) 1997-2010
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend
>   Technologies
>       with Suhosin v0.9.37.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014, by SektionEins GmbH

What is something wrong?

Comment: Ask your host how to update (you might be able to use a custom php.ini).

Answer (score 1):

You need to update PHP Ideally to 5.5.x you are on a very old and insecure version. I would contact your host to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you received is pretty self explanatory.

You're running PHP 5.3.3 and Joomla 3.3+ requires PHP 5.3.10

You're PHP version is behind the minimum requirement, therefore you need to update PHP.